# set the width and height of jquery popup large images

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I have used a jquery popup gallery for my website where I want to set the resizable image to some fixed height and width. I cant get the exact code here is my code for the gallery

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/top_up-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  TopUp.addPresets({
    "#images a": {
      fixed: 0,
      group: "images",
      modal: 0,
      title: "gallery"

    },

    "#movies": {
      resizable: 0
    }
  });
</script>
```

and code for images in body part

```
  <span id="images">
        <a href="images/photos/1.jpg" toptions="overlayClose = 1">
          <img src="images/thumbnails/1.jpg"/>
        </a>
         <a href="images/photos/1.jpg" toptions="overlayClose = 1">
          <img src="images/thumbnails/1.jpg"/>
        </a>

      </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

image dimensions can be controlled through CSS. If you are using a jQuery library to display your images, then there will be an associated stylesheet that you can edit to set the displayed image dimensions. Or there may be an option to set the displayed image width in the initializer. Your alternative is to overwrite any styles set by the library.

In your custom stylesheet you could try the following, assuming a fixed width of 300px,

```
img{width:300px !important;}
```

or

```
a img{width:300px !important;}
```

or

```
#images img{width:300px !important;}
```

or

```
a img{width:300px !important;}
```

or

```
#images a img{width:300px !important;}
```

adding !important ensures that it is the style that is used, it should overwrite any other styles already defined by the library you are using. [Click for more info on !important](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

hope this helps